# Get Array value from nested Array with Array as parent/child mapping

Tags: php, arrays, dynamic, mapping

Lets say I have an array like this:

```
$a = array(
    "foo",
    "bar"
);
```

and

```
$b = array(
    "foo" => array(
        "bar" => 1
    )
);
```

and I want to use `$a` to get `$b[$a[0]][$a[1]]`

Assumptions are 1..* length of `$a` and 1..* levels in `$b`.

Comment: Please share what you have tried.

Comment: ... and what you are attempting to obtain. Why does not `$b[$a[0]][$a[1]]` work for you?

Comment: @Eineki he wants a solution that works for any level of nesting

Comment: @Barmar I guessed the scope a couple of minutes after the comment posting (it still a poorly expressed question to me). I was working on the topics but you came out with a nice solution (I would just embrace the code into a try...catch to manage missing index)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$result = $b;
foreach ($a as $index) {
    $result = $result[$index];
}
echo $result;
```

Comment: That doesn't work at all! Because at the second iteration it's: $b["bar"], which don't exists!

Answer (score 1):

This should work for you:

```
<?php

    //As an example
    $a = array(
        "foo",
        "bar",
        "xy",
        "ab"
    );

    $b = array(
        "foo" => array(
            "bar" => array(
                "xy" => array(
                    "ab" => 14  
                ),
            ),
        )
    );

    $end = $b;
    foreach ($a as $index)
        $end = $end[$index];

    echo $end;

?>
```

Output:

```
14
```